# The other notifications is lost the click behaviour, when a notification is chosen at device's system tray in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-notifications, android-launcher

If there're two my app's notifications at device's system tray, the user choose one notification, the app's opening but all of other notifications is lost the click behavior, it means user cannot click them anymore. How can I prevent this action?

My code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.test))
            .setContentText(messageBody);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(NotificationViewActivity.MESSAGE_EXTRA, messageBody);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                     intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                                           getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(50) + 1, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detected my root cause in below code

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Because the request code is the same for all notifications, so when we click to the one notification, the other lost their click listener. Fix like below codes

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int mId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
                        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.imagename)
                                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                                        .setContentText("message")
                                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                        .setAutoCancel(true);
                        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, activityname.class);
//activityname is the name of activity which you want to launch
                        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

                        // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
                        // started Activity.
                        // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
                        // your application to the Home screen.
                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
                        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                                        0,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                                );
                        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
                        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: I used your code, and it doesn't work like I want. It clears all the previous notifications. I want to keep all of them when the user click the one notification.

Comment: I just update my problem, please review it again. Sorry for the previous question